# Ignore some files from SVN commit

Tags: svn

Have to remove the logs and schema.rb from the svn as that is machine dependent.My schema is not migrating after the update as the schema revision on different machine is of different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with adding svn:ignore property. CD to where your files are located and try the following command:

```
svn propset svn:ignore schema.rb .
```

Note the dot at the end of the command.

Check that the files are ignored:

```
svn status --no-ignore
```

Then commit.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need to ignore file while adding/commiting. To heal the situation first add unneeded files/patterns to [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) keyword.

Then make a backup of these files for yourself and remove them from SVN repository and commit removal. Next, copy your backups back to working copy. These files will not be visible by SVN any longer as you have added them for "ignoring".